# Django, Boto, S3: Why am I not getting a response suddenly?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

This has been driving me crazy and I can't figure out where the issue is.  AWS is having issues right now, but this problem was happening before all that and continues to exhibit same behavior.

Summary: I have an admin field that uploads images to S3 and stores the path in the database.  On a fresh apache restart, it works fine for about 20 minutes.  Then it stops working and just hangs on 'waiting for response from *domain*'  That's it, no error message, just sits there, waiting, and won't work again until I restart apache.  And after restarting apache it works flawlessly until it stops, which happens after 20 minutes best I can tell and is not cause by more or less traffic or a certain number of inserts, deletes, etc.

Here's code for the model:

```
class SampleImage(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    front_image = S3EnabledImageField(upload_to='samples')
    back_image = S3EnabledImageField(upload_to='samples')
```

Code for S3EnabledImageField:

```
class S3EnabledImageField(models.ImageField):
    def generate_filename(self, instance, filename):
        path_join = os.path.join(self.get_directory_name(), self.get_filename(filename))
        return path_join.replace("\\", "/")

    def __init__(self, bucket=settings.BUCKET_NAME, verbose_name=None, name=None, width_field=None, height_field=None, **kwargs):
        if settings.USE_AMAZON_S3:
            self.connection = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
            if not self.connection.lookup(bucket):
                self.connection.create_bucket(bucket)
            self.bucket = self.connection.get_bucket(bucket)
            kwargs['storage'] = S3Storage(self.bucket)
        super(S3EnabledImageField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, width_field, height_field, **kwargs)
```

Code for S3Storage:

```
class S3Storage(FileSystemStorage):
    def __init__(self, bucket=None, location=None, base_url=None):
        if location is None:
            location = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        if base_url is None:
            base_url = settings.MEDIA_URL
        self.location = os.path.abspath(location)
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.base_url = base_url

    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        class S3File(File):
            def __init__(self, key):
                self.key = key

            def size(self):
                return self.key.size

            def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.key.read(*args, **kwargs)

            def write(self, content):
                self.key.set_contents_from_string(content)

            def close(self):
                self.key.close()

        return S3File(Key(self.bucket, name))

    def _save(self, name, content):
        key = Key(self.bucket, name)
        if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path'):
            key.set_contents_from_filename(content.temporary_file_path())
        elif isinstance(content, File):
            key.set_contents_from_file(content)
        else:
            key.set_contents_from_string(content)
        key.make_public()

        return name

    def delete(self, name):
        self.bucket.delete_key(name)

    def exists(self, name):
        return Key(self.bucket, name).exists()

    def listdir(self, path):
        return [key.name for key in self.bucket.list()]

    def path(self, name):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def size(self, name):
        return self.bucket.get_key(name).size

    def url(self, name):
        return Key(self.bucket, name).generate_url(100000)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure by looking at your code. But, sounds like there might be connections that aren't getting closed?  At any rate, why not work with:

https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/S3Storage

?

django-storages has worked well for me.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, are you aware of a way to close the connections?  Django storages also uses s3boto, but looks like I can try the other s3 backend it provides, may try rewriting in that, just a pita and doesn't explain why it works then stops working after 20 mins.